# AngularJS delete html element bound to $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to delete an angular x-editable form on success method of a promise.

```
<div ng-repeat="(rang, course) in box.value track by $index">
   <!-- form should be gone after promise resolution -->
   <form                                   
      editable-form 
      name="forms.{{box.key}}{{rang}}"
      ng-if="forms[box.key + rang]" <!-- tried with ng-if which did not work -->
      >
   </form>
</div>
```

In the controller I have the following.

```
$scope.forms = {};

var promise = api.updateCurrentUser(data);
if (action === 'delete') {
    promise.success(function() {
       // something should happen to delete form tried
       - delete $scope.forms[key + range]
       - $scope.forms[key + range] = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove only the <form> or the whole repeated <div> item?

Comment: opps yes I meant the whole div for that form

Answer (score 0):

The delete approach is correct I was just deleting the wrong thing

```
   if (action === 'delete') {
       promise.success(function () {
           $scope.accordionBoxs.forEach(function (box, index) {
               if (box.key === key) {
                   delete $scope.accordionBoxs[index]['value'][range];
               }
           });

       });
   }
```